# Updating vim on remote host

Tags: vim, upgrade, remote, hosting-services

I am currently running a shared bluehost account. The current version of vim on the server is 7.2. I have recently installed 7.4 on my local machine and some of the features I've grown accustomed to are not available with 7.2.

So, my question is:
Is there any way to update vim on a shared hosting account? I did some digging and was able to successfully install python but have not found a way to upgrade vim.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ssh account, You can have to download vim source code into your home dir, and for compile , you have to pass pwd to --prefix :

```
./configure --prefix=`pwd` && make &&  make install
```

Because you don't have any permission to package manager, such as yum , apt, pacman  and so on.